# MemSQL code generation has failed: Failed to codegen

Tags: singlestore

Ihave workstation of 250 gb Ram and 4 tb SSD. The memsql has a table that contains 1 billion records each of which 44 columns with 500 gb data. When I run the following query on that table

```
SELECT  count(*) ct,name,age FROM research.all_data  group by name having count(*) >100 order by ct desc
```

I got the following error

> MemSQL code generation has failed

I made a restart to the server and after that I got another error

> Not enough memory available to complete the current request. The request was not processed

I gave the server maximum mermory 220 GB and max_table_memory 190 GB.

why that error could happen?

why memsql consuming 140 gb from memory however I am using column store?

Comment: These types of issues are easier to debug via our public slack channel: http://chat.memsql.com/

Answer (score 1):

For "MemSQL code generation has failed", check the tracelog (http://docs.memsql.com/docs/trace-log) on the MemSQL node where the error was hit for more details - this can mean a lot of different things.

MemSQL needs memory to process query results, hold some metadata, etc. even though columnstore data lives on disk. Check memsql status info to see what is using memory - https://knowledgebase.memsql.com/hc/en-us/articles/208759276-What-is-using-memory-on-my-leaves-.